# Kafka python consumer reading all the messages when started

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am using the below code to read messages from a topic. I am facing two issues.
Whenever i start consumer, it is reading all the messages in the queue? 
How do read only the unread messages?

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
for message in consumer:
    consumer.commit() 
    # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
    # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
    print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                          message.offset, message.key,
                                          message.value))
```

Comment: I think you have to `consumer.commit()` after reading out.

Comment: thanks @KenjiNoguchi, i tried with consumer.commit() and still not working. any hints

Answer (score 11):

As @Kenji said you have to commit the offsets with `consumer.commit()`. If you don't want to commit manually you can enable autocommit by passing `enable_auto_commit=True` to your `KafkaConsumer`. You may also want to tune `auto_commit_interval_ms` which is the interval in milliseconds between each automatic commit. See here: http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html.

Comment: thanks @se7entyse7en i tried with consumer.commit() and still not working. any hints

Comment: @user3570620, maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579815/kafka-python-how-do-i-commit-a-partition