# Kafka Python Consumer Commit API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I need to do a programmatic commit using kafka-python api.
From the the documentation i see that I need to use the api below, but couldn't find a good usage example:

[image]

It needs offsets as a dictionary of TopicPartition and OffsetMetadata.
I was thinking of using the assignment() API on the consumer which returns me the list of TopicPartitions of the current consumer. For the OffsetAndMetadata, i can set the offset but I don't get what i need to set for the metadata attribute. The documentation isn't that helpful.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Java API is any indication, the `metadata` is optional - https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html. Also, this SO may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579815/kafka-python-how-do-i-commit-a-partition?

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is optional in OffsetAndMetadata object.  You can pass `None` as the metadata value.

Kafka does not use this metadata internally so it is effectively an opaque byte array that can be used to store application-specific data.

More info here: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/645