# Kafka error Out of Memory when consumer uses param group_id

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to read info. from Kafka topic using  python-kafka.

I can read info. properly from beginning every time I restart the consumer, but if I try to save readead info. using group_id to read topic from last readed when restarting, it produces an error in Kafka.

I'm using windows 10, kafka 2.11-2.1.0 and python-kafka 1.4.6 with python 3.x

I've read about the right way to read from an offset, but It doesn't work properly in my case.
[kafka-python consumer start reading from offset (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799077/kafka-python-consumer-start-reading-from-offset-automatically)

With this code I'm able to read topic info. from beginning every time I restart the consumer

```py
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                                     value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))
```

But I'm getting kafka error when starting the consumer if I inform the group_id

```py
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                                     enable_auto_commit=True,
                                     auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
                                     group_id='my-group',
                                     value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))
```

After Error I have to delete kafka and zookeeper tmp info. to be able to restart again kafka.

This is the kafka log ( I've cut off some of the logs trying to do it more readable)

```
rmark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2019-07-19 18:41:02,353] INFO [Partition __consumer_offsets-15 broker=0] __consumer_offsets-15 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-07-19 18:41:02,567] ERROR Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-12 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:126)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:634)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:542)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:276)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2071)

....................

... 45 more
[2019-07-19 18:41:02,767] ERROR Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-31 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:126)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:634)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:542)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:276)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2071)

..............

-19 18:41:02,773] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error while making broker the leader for partition Topic: __consumer_offsets; Partition: 31; Leader: None; AllReplicas: ; InSyncReplicas:  in dir None (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-31 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:126)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:634)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:542)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:276)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2071)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:691)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:659)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:659)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:199)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:195)
        at kafka.utils.Pool$$anon$2.apply(Pool.scala:61)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:60)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:194)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$7.apply(Partition.scala:373)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$7.apply(Partition.scala:373)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$5.apply(Partition.scala:373)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$5.apply(Partition.scala:367)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:259)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:367)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1162)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1160)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1160)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1072)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:185)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:110)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        ... 45 more


.............

[2019-07-19 19:13:59,114] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-34 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,115] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-37 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,116] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-40 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,117] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-43 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,123] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-34 in 8 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,124] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-46 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,126] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-37 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,126] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-49 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,127] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-40 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,128] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,128] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-43 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,129] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-4 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,130] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-46 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,131] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-7 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,132] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-49 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,132] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-10 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,139] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-2 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,140] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-5 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,134] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-1 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,141] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-8 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,142] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-4 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,142] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-11 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,144] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-14 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,143] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-7 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,145] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-17 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,146] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-10 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,147] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-20 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,154] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-2 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,155] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-23 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,155] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-5 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,156] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-26 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,157] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-8 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,158] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-29 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,159] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-11 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,160] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-0 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,161] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-14 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,164] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-15 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,167] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-17 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,168] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-18 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,169] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-20 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,170] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-21 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,171] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-24 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,170] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-23 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,172] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-27 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,175] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-26 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,178] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-30 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,179] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-29 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,179] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-33 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,180] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-0 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,181] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-36 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,182] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-39 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,182] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-15 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,183] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-42 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,184] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-18 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,188] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-45 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,191] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-21 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,192] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-48 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,192] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-24 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,194] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-27 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,196] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-30 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,197] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-33 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,198] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-30, __consumer_offsets-8, __consumer_offsets-21, __consumer_offsets-4, __consumer_offsets-27, __consumer_offsets-7, __consumer_offsets-46, __consumer_offsets-33, __consumer_offsets-23, __consumer_offsets-49, __consumer_offsets-36, __consumer_offsets-42, __consumer_offsets-18, __consumer_offsets-37, __consumer_offsets-15, __consumer_offsets-24, topic_TFM-0, __consumer_offsets-17, __consumer_offsets-48, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-2, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-14, __consumer_offsets-20, __consumer_offsets-0, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-45, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-5, __consumer_offsets-26, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-34, __consumer_offsets-10, __consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,203] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-36 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,205] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-39 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,205] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-30, __consumer_offsets-8, __consumer_offsets-21, __consumer_offsets-4, __consumer_offsets-27, __consumer_offsets-7, __consumer_offsets-46, __consumer_offsets-33, __consumer_offsets-23, __consumer_offsets-49, __consumer_offsets-36, __consumer_offsets-42, __consumer_offsets-18, __consumer_offsets-37, __consumer_offsets-15, __consumer_offsets-24, topic_TFM-0, __consumer_offsets-17, __consumer_offsets-48, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-2, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-14, __consumer_offsets-20, __consumer_offsets-0, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-45, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-5, __consumer_offsets-26, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-34, __consumer_offsets-10, __consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,206] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-42 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,208] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-45 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,210] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-48 in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,237] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-30,__consumer_offsets-8,__consumer_offsets-21,__consumer_offsets-4,__consumer_offsets-27,__consumer_offsets-7,__consumer_offsets-46,__consumer_offsets-33,__consumer_offsets-23,__consumer_offsets-49,__consumer_offsets-36,__consumer_offsets-42,__consumer_offsets-18,__consumer_offsets-37,__consumer_offsets-15,__consumer_offsets-24,topic_TFM-0,__consumer_offsets-17,__consumer_offsets-48,__consumer_offsets-11,__consumer_offsets-2,__consumer_offsets-43,__consumer_offsets-14,__consumer_offsets-20,__consumer_offsets-0,__consumer_offsets-39,__consumer_offsets-45,__consumer_offsets-1,__consumer_offsets-5,__consumer_offsets-26,__consumer_offsets-29,__consumer_offsets-34,__consumer_offsets-10,__consumer_offsets-40 and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory C:\tmp\kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,239] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-19 19:13:59,246] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\tmp\kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` ... You need to increase the heap space for the broker, it seems

Comment: eg. `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx2G -Xms2G"`

Comment: Thank you cricket_007 and Giorgios for your quick response. I've tried to increase the heap by changing the script kafka-server-start.bat.

Comment: But when I set the var  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx2G -Xms2G"and try to start the script then I get error " Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap". If I set the option to "-Xmx1G -Xms1G" (by default value is "-Xmx512M -Xms512M") kafka starts, but the out of memory error happens again.  Sould I change any other var? Thanks a lot